# Oracle Trigger errors

Tags: oracle, trigger

I have a tables ENV_CONFIG and ENV_CONFIG_HIST where the latter table should get a new record on any insertion to the former. The trigger seems pretty straight forward but I'm getting compilation errors:

- line 5  : SQL Statement ignored (Insert ...)
- line 13 : Column not allowed here (,new.PARAM_VALUE)

What am I missing?

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_ENV_CONFIG_INSERT
  AFTER INSERT
  ON ENV_CONFIG
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ENV_CONFIG_HIST (
    PARAM_NAME
    ,PARAM_DESCR
    ,PARAM_VALUE
  ) VALUES (
    new.PARAM_NAME
   ,new.PARAM_DESCR
   ,new.PARAM_VALUE
 );
END;
```

Comment: it should be `:new`, not `new`.   "The NEW and OLD keywords, when specified in the WHEN clause, are not considered bind variables, so are not preceded by a colon (:). However, you must precede NEW and OLD with a colon in all references other than the WHEN clause."   (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm)

Comment: @a1ex07 Thanks for the note about the semi-colon. I had used it in an earlier incarnation but had gotten errors - probably due some other issue. To finally get this to compile I had to fiddle around with the constraints on the HIST table by matching the nullability on the non HIST table.

Comment: If I use the semi-colon (:new) in Oracle SQL Developer's trigger editor it works fine. However if I run the same script in a query window it will prompt for the bind variable.

Comment: Instead of running it with "F9" (Alt+Enter), execute it with "F5" (run script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need add Colon character (:) before new keyword same as below query:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_ENV_CONFIG_INSERT
AFTER INSERT
  ON ENV_CONFIG
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ENV_CONFIG_HIST (
    PARAM_NAME
    ,PARAM_DESCR
    ,PARAM_VALUE
  ) VALUES (
    :new.PARAM_NAME
   ,:new.PARAM_DESCR
   ,:new.PARAM_VALUE
 );
END;
```